# how to read json file having several json objects and extract values in jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, json, parsing

I have this json file:

```
{"created_at":"Thu Mar 15 20:05:53 +0000 2018","id":974376156186206208,"id_str":"974376156186206208","text":"RT @dtrubchenkov: #eth_town #ethereum #game #crypto\nLast but mandatory, you have to follow their Twitter account: https:\/\/t.co\/rjjvVStl6z.\u2026","source":"\u003ca href=\"https:\/\/discoveringmypath.wixsite.com\/discoveringmypath\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003ereadysetgame\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":969005342125371393,"id_str":"969005342125371393","name":"ReadySetGame","screen_name":"ReadySetGame3","location":null,"url":null,"description":"Ready set game. Created by @Discovermypath","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":266,"friends_count":1,"listed_count":14,"favourites_count":0,"statuses_count":16543,"created_at":"Thu Mar 01 00:24:11 +0000 2018","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"F5F8FA","profile_background_image_url":"","profile_background_image_url_https":"","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"1DA1F2","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/969014017988546561\/oTXMTMQD_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/969014017988546561\/oTXMTMQD_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/969005342125371393\/1519865955","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"retweeted_status":{"created_at":"Mon Mar 12 15:44:38 +0000 2018","id":973223247746609152,"id_str":"973223247746609152","text":"#eth_town #ethereum #game #crypto\nLast but mandatory, you have to follow their Twitter account:\u2026 https:\/\/t.co\/vFhvjsQGZA","source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web Client\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":true,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":956518734189006851,"id_str":"956518734189006851","name":"\u0414\u0438\u043c\u0430 \u0422\u0440\u0443\u0431\u0447\u0435\u043d\u043a\u043e\u0432","screen_name":"dtrubchenkov","location":null,"url":null,"description":"\u0412\u0435\u0441\u0435\u043b\u044b\u0439, \u043e\u0431\u0449\u0438\u0442\u0435\u043b\u044c\u043d\u044b\u0439 \u0438 \u0436\u0438\u0437\u043d\u0435\u0440\u0430\u0434\u043e\u0441\u0442\u043d\u044b\u0439","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":1817,"friends_count":2062,"listed_count":5,"favourites_count":1500,"statuses_count":1624,"created_at":"Thu Jan 25 13:26:52 +0000 2018","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"lang":"ru","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"F5F8FA","profile_background_image_url":"","profile_background_image_url_https":"","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"1DA1F2","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/956519643400765441\/adZtSbo3_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/956519643400765441\/adZtSbo3_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/956518734189006851\/1519292876","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"extended_tweet":{"full_text":"#eth_town #ethereum #game #crypto\nLast but mandatory, you have to follow their Twitter account: https:\/\/t.co\/rjjvVStl6z. And you must like and follow their Facebook page: https:\/\/t.co\/fcQ3EyaFXa. The team will verify each subscription\u2026","display_text_range":[0,235],"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"eth_town","indices":[0,9]},{"text":"ethereum","indices":[10,19]},{"text":"game","indices":[20,25]},{"text":"crypto","indices":[26,33]}],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/rjjvVStl6z","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/eth_town","display_url":"twitter.com\/eth_town","indices":[96,119]},{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/fcQ3EyaFXa","expanded_url":"https:\/\/fb.me\/eth.town","display_url":"fb.me\/eth.town","indices":[171,194]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]}},"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":1,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"eth_town","indices":[0,9]},{"text":"ethereum","indices":[10,19]},{"text":"game","indices":[20,25]},{"text":"crypto","indices":[26,33]}],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/vFhvjsQGZA","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/973223247746609152","display_url":"twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/9\u2026","indices":[97,120]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en"},"is_quote_status":false,"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"eth_town","indices":[18,27]},{"text":"ethereum","indices":[28,37]},{"text":"game","indices":[38,43]},{"text":"crypto","indices":[44,51]}],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/rjjvVStl6z","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/eth_town","display_url":"twitter.com\/eth_town","indices":[114,137]}],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"dtrubchenkov","name":"\u0414\u0438\u043c\u0430 \u0422\u0440\u0443\u0431\u0447\u0435\u043d\u043a\u043e\u0432","id":956518734189006851,"id_str":"956518734189006851","indices":[3,16]}],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1521144353325"}

{"created_at":"Thu Mar 15 20:05:53 +0000 2018","id":974376157247393792,"id_str":"974376157247393792","text":"Hoje eu vou deixar como p\u00fablico.\nhttps:\/\/t.co\/f3Nr8ZjYPV\n#PTBR #game #indie #gameplay #VideoGame #VisualNovel\u2026 https:\/\/t.co\/KJaWnStVyB","display_text_range":[0,140],"source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter Web Client\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":true,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_user_id":null,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"user":{"id":1663346617,"id_str":"1663346617","name":"Player Banzai","screen_name":"PlayerBanzai","location":null,"url":null,"description":"Ol\u00e1 pessoal! Meu canal de games foca mais nos jogos de RPG Makers, de terror e de anime, mas tamb\u00e9m posto de outros estilos. Posto tamb\u00e9m quiz dos mesmos.","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":165,"friends_count":129,"listed_count":2,"favourites_count":1038,"statuses_count":8521,"created_at":"Sun Aug 11 19:48:14 +0000 2013","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"lang":"pt","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","profile_background_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000049385411\/cc967c6303c376407da9f249a0f63ab4.jpeg","profile_background_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_background_images\/378800000049385411\/cc967c6303c376407da9f249a0f63ab4.jpeg","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"0084B4","profile_sidebar_border_color":"FFFFFF","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/953299057228898305\/ARtkim0P_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/953299057228898305\/ARtkim0P_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/1663346617\/1516068748","default_profile":false,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"extended_tweet":{"full_text":"Hoje eu vou deixar como p\u00fablico.\nhttps:\/\/t.co\/f3Nr8ZjYPV\n#PTBR #game #indie #gameplay #VideoGame #VisualNovel #Anime #Encontros #Romance #Casual, #bishoujo #KatawaShoujo #jogosindie #manga #games #gameplay #gameplays #KatawaShoujoemi #emiKatawaShoujo https:\/\/t.co\/iedR1YMRLG","display_text_range":[0,250],"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"PTBR","indices":[57,62]},{"text":"game","indices":[63,68]},{"text":"indie","indices":[69,75]},{"text":"gameplay","indices":[76,85]},{"text":"VideoGame","indices":[86,96]},{"text":"VisualNovel","indices":[97,109]},{"text":"Anime","indices":[110,116]},{"text":"Encontros","indices":[117,127]},{"text":"Romance","indices":[128,136]},{"text":"Casual","indices":[137,144]},{"text":"bishoujo","indices":[146,155]},{"text":"KatawaShoujo","indices":[156,169]},{"text":"jogosindie","indices":[170,181]},{"text":"manga","indices":[182,188]},{"text":"games","indices":[189,195]},{"text":"gameplay","indices":[196,205]},{"text":"gameplays","indices":[206,216]},{"text":"KatawaShoujoemi","indices":[217,233]},{"text":"emiKatawaShoujo","indices":[234,250]}],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/f3Nr8ZjYPV","expanded_url":"https:\/\/youtu.be\/uiG_HaI3ipA","display_url":"youtu.be\/uiG_HaI3ipA","indices":[33,56]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[],"media":[{"id":974376006537699328,"id_str":"974376006537699328","indices":[251,274],"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/DYWt0MNX4AAr7H_.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/DYWt0MNX4AAr7H_.jpg","url":"https:\/\/t.co\/iedR1YMRLG","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/iedR1YMRLG","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/PlayerBanzai\/status\/974376157247393792\/photo\/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"medium":{"w":1200,"h":675,"resize":"fit"},"small":{"w":680,"h":383,"resize":"fit"},"large":{"w":1280,"h":720,"resize":"fit"}}}]},"extended_entities":{"media":[{"id":974376006537699328,"id_str":"974376006537699328","indices":[251,274],"media_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/DYWt0MNX4AAr7H_.jpg","media_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/media\/DYWt0MNX4AAr7H_.jpg","url":"https:\/\/t.co\/iedR1YMRLG","display_url":"pic.twitter.com\/iedR1YMRLG","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/PlayerBanzai\/status\/974376157247393792\/photo\/1","type":"photo","sizes":{"thumb":{"w":150,"h":150,"resize":"crop"},"medium":{"w":1200,"h":675,"resize":"fit"},"small":{"w":680,"h":383,"resize":"fit"},"large":{"w":1280,"h":720,"resize":"fit"}}}]}},"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"PTBR","indices":[57,62]},{"text":"game","indices":[63,68]},{"text":"indie","indices":[69,75]},{"text":"gameplay","indices":[76,85]},{"text":"VideoGame","indices":[86,96]},{"text":"VisualNovel","indices":[97,109]}],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/f3Nr8ZjYPV","expanded_url":"https:\/\/youtu.be\/uiG_HaI3ipA","display_url":"youtu.be\/uiG_HaI3ipA","indices":[33,56]},{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/KJaWnStVyB","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/974376157247393792","display_url":"twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/9\u2026","indices":[111,134]}],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"possibly_sensitive":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"pt","timestamp_ms":"1521144353578"}

{"created_at":"Thu Mar 15 20:05:56 +0000 2018","id":974376170111291393,"id_str":"974376170111291393","text":"@OdysseyProtocol The CEO, team, speed of development (When I invested in this in the ICO the market was doing ok an\u2026 https:\/\/t.co\/709gad6CDf","display_text_range":[17,140],"source":"\u003ca href=\"http:\/\/twitter.com\/download\/android\" rel=\"nofollow\"\u003eTwitter for Android\u003c\/a\u003e","truncated":true,"in_reply_to_status_id":974349475195039744,"in_reply_to_status_id_str":"974349475195039744","in_reply_to_user_id":941287889916321792,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":"941287889916321792","in_reply_to_screen_name":"CryptonianJake","user":{"id":941287889916321792,"id_str":"941287889916321792","name":"Tsvetan Peshev","screen_name":"CryptonianJake","location":"Vienna, Austria","url":"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/HungerForTheLife\/?ref=br_rs","description":"Crypto Enthusiast!\n\n#OCN #TRX  #BlackBelt Martial Artist and Champion multiple times.\n\nDisclaimer: Nothing I say Is financial advise, do your own research.","translator_type":"none","protected":false,"verified":false,"followers_count":309,"friends_count":343,"listed_count":2,"favourites_count":2113,"statuses_count":1929,"created_at":"Thu Dec 14 12:44:56 +0000 2017","utc_offset":null,"time_zone":null,"geo_enabled":false,"lang":"en","contributors_enabled":false,"is_translator":false,"profile_background_color":"F5F8FA","profile_background_image_url":"","profile_background_image_url_https":"","profile_background_tile":false,"profile_link_color":"1DA1F2","profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","profile_text_color":"333333","profile_use_background_image":true,"profile_image_url":"http:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/956861579756220416\/808lK38z_normal.jpg","profile_image_url_https":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_images\/956861579756220416\/808lK38z_normal.jpg","profile_banner_url":"https:\/\/pbs.twimg.com\/profile_banners\/941287889916321792\/1516968220","default_profile":true,"default_profile_image":false,"following":null,"follow_request_sent":null,"notifications":null},"geo":null,"coordinates":null,"place":null,"contributors":null,"is_quote_status":false,"extended_tweet":{"full_text":"@OdysseyProtocol The CEO, team, speed of development (When I invested in this in the ICO the market was doing ok and I got a 4 x 3 days after the ICO ended, turning to a 10x eventually.\nPartnerships are HUGE! #GTC #GAME.COM #TRX #OBIKE and more... #Spring will be #amazing once #crypto is stable.","display_text_range":[17,296],"entities":{"hashtags":[{"text":"GTC","indices":[209,213]},{"text":"GAME","indices":[214,219]},{"text":"TRX","indices":[224,228]},{"text":"OBIKE","indices":[229,235]},{"text":"Spring","indices":[248,255]},{"text":"amazing","indices":[264,272]},{"text":"crypto","indices":[278,285]}],"urls":[],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"OdysseyProtocol","name":"The Odyssey Protocol (OCN)","id":946273319036137472,"id_str":"946273319036137472","indices":[0,16]}],"symbols":[]}},"quote_count":0,"reply_count":0,"retweet_count":0,"favorite_count":0,"entities":{"hashtags":[],"urls":[{"url":"https:\/\/t.co\/709gad6CDf","expanded_url":"https:\/\/twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/974376170111291393","display_url":"twitter.com\/i\/web\/status\/9\u2026","indices":[117,140]}],"user_mentions":[{"screen_name":"OdysseyProtocol","name":"The Odyssey Protocol (OCN)","id":946273319036137472,"id_str":"946273319036137472","indices":[0,16]}],"symbols":[]},"favorited":false,"retweeted":false,"filter_level":"low","lang":"en","timestamp_ms":"1521144356645"}
```

it has several json object, how do I use python to read this file and get the information, such as "hashtags" and "created_at"? json.load always has error:Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)

Answer (score 0):

The file seems to contain line delimited JSON texts so you should be able to iterate over the lines of the file and load each as a separate JSON object (Python dict in this case), then access the specific values by key:

```
import json

with open('file.json') as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.rstrip():
            data = json.loads(line)
            print(data['created_at'], data['hashtags'])
```

Note that `"hashtags"` is not a valid key in the JSON data provided, but the above should be illustrative enough to solve your problem.

[`line.rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=rstrip#str.rstrip) is used to remove any trailing whitespace from the line so that empty lines can be filtered out.

Comment: I try it but it still has the same problem. the error is: JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1).

Comment: You can test that the code I've shown works for the data that you have posted. If the actual data is different then it might not work. Check that the data you are using is the same. If you are using Python 2 and you you have a file that uses different line termination characters than your platform expects you could try universal newline mode: `open('file.json', 'Ur')`

Comment: Yes, you're right......in current situation how to do?  line spacing is different from line delimited....I don't aware this before.

Comment: Your edit to the data suggests that there is a blank line between each JSON text? If so you need to skip the blank lines - I've updated the answer to show how.